# Empty and blank WordPress login page

Tags: php, wordpress, logging

I hosted my local project to online. I can see the website but I can't access to the admin panel because when I search `domain/wp-admin` it shows a blank page without any error .
This is my main domain `http://qoute.onlinedev.me/wp-admin/`
Who can solve this?

Comment: you need to enable debugging to see what's going one and check your log file beside try to login through the following link: http://qoute.onlinedev.me/wp-login.php

Comment: http://qoute.onlinedev.me/wp-login.php is working, there might be some security plugin that is hiding the wp-admin area.

Comment: @ale I haven't any plugin to my project.

Comment: there might be some .htaccess rule that prevents you from opening the wp-admin.php. And one other thought that just came up in my mind: Do you have your site installed in separate folder of `public_html` like `/public_html/some_other_folder/`. If so your admin  entry point will be sitename.com/some_other_folder/wp-admin.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I make the `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in my `wp-config.php` file.
It shows the issues and errors.

**Note: Try it online**
because it doesn't show any issue in my localhost but when I upload it on online Host it shows that I have the issue with `functions.php` file at first line.

> **FIXES: Just a space before the `<?php` tag.**
> I remove space and it fix my issue.

Comment: It may be because while uploading files `functions.php` contents messed up removing spaces and enters you will need to have proper spacing and enters in `functions.php` file

Comment: Okay, I fix that just put my solution to help someone, it is so crazy that one space before `<?php` tag waste my time

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sure people will come here later looking for this. I experianced
> same just today. For those folks, putting it as short as possible I
> can here

## Make sure no blank spaces near `<?php`. (See screenshot.. remove it)

[image]